# How can I list tags en Google Data Catalog?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-data-catalog

I'm creating tag templates programmatically and it doesn't appear in the section "Tag Templates" (the creation of each tag template was successful because I can attach it in each table), but when I create those tag templates by hand, they appear as a list.

Btw I'm trying to list the tag templates that I created, with the following sentence:

```
tag_list = datacatalog.list_tags(parent=f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}")
```

but when I print it says

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Malformed Data Catalog resource name projects/sybogames-analytics-dev/locations/us.
```

anyone knows why?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the Data Catalog service but, looking at the possible methods in [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), I think (!?) you may need to terminate `parent` with `/entrygroup/{entrygroup}`.

There are 2 (!?) possible methods for `list_tags`:

1. [entryGroups.entries.tag_list](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.entryGroups.entries.tags/list)
2. [entryGroup.tags.list](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.entryGroups.tags/list)

Both define `parent` similarly and require `/entryGroups/{entrygroup}`:

> The resource can be an `Entry` or an `EntryGroup` (without `/entries/{entries}` at the end). It takes the form `projects/{project}/locations/{location}/entryGroups/{entrygroup}/entries/{entries}`.

You can use APIs Explorer to invoke either method to test it.

You can also use [`gcloud data-catalog tags list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/data-catalog/tags/list) and, if you append `--log-http` to it, you'll be able to see exactly what underlying REST call is being made.

Comment: What is Entry/Entry Group mean in this context?